# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in http.get

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an error when I convert the data to JSON
I get the information from the server but I get an error. I encountered this error after updating http

```
  Future<List<Ratemodel>> getRates(String id) async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(ApiConstants.baseUrl + ApiConstants.rate + id));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return allRates(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
```

error

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

```
List<Ratemodel> allRates(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return new List<Ratemodel>.from(jsonData.map((x) => Ratemodel.fromJson(x)));
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `http.get`. Your `allRates` function expects a `String` argument. `jsonDecode` likely is returning a `List`.  Note that `allRates` expects to call `json.decode` itself.  Either `allRates` should decode the JSON string or its caller should decode it, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allRates(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

jsonDecode is not returning a string. So you cannot pass that into `allRates` like this.
I would suggest you put `allRates(response.body)` instead.